# flask - излишнее количество функций

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

У меня есть много функций, от которых хотелось бы избавиться, например:

```
@app.route('/ranobe/')
def ranobe_main():
    return render_template('ranobe/ranobe_main.html')


@app.route('/anime/sign_in/')
def sign_in():
    return render_template('login_or_register/sign_in.html')
```

И множество других похожих функций, которые просто ссылаются html файлы. Можно ли как-то сократить количество строк, чтобы не повторять постоянно одни и те же действия? Если да, то напишите в качестве примера код, который сократит большую часть повторяющихся функций, пожалуйста. Также хотелось бы, чтобы привели в пример код, который будет лучше выглядеть, так как я учусь. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Я не сильно знаю Flask но мне кажется что это сделать нельзя хотя бы по той причине что по сути каждая функция это отдельная страница, вот подумайте логически как одна функция может обработать 2страницы?

Comment: @Dendi255 Да в теории наверное можно даже сделать, но не очень понятно зачем

Comment: @CrazyElf Хотелось бы избавиться от большого количества кода в проге, но как я понял, не получится

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать функцию для создания обработчиков:

```
def template_route(path, template_file):
   @app.route(path)
   def handler():
       return render_template(template_file)
   return handler

ranobe_main = template_route('/ranobe', 'ranobe/ranobe_main.html')
sign_in = template_route('/anime/sign_in/', 'login_or_register/sign_in.html')
```

Можно пойти дальше, как предложил CrazyElf:

```
def template_routes(*args):
   assert len(args) % 2 == 0 
   for i in range(0, len(args), 2):
       path, template_file = args[i], args[i+1]
       template_route(path, template_file)


template_routes(
   '/ranobe', 'ranobe/ranobe_main.html',
   '/anime/sign_in/', 'login_or_register/sign_in.html',
)
```

Comment: большое спасибо, так код сократится в несколько раз

Comment: Хм, интересная мысль. Только есть ли смысл отдельные переменные заводить, может лучше сделать список/кортеж и туда эти функции размещать? Красивше будет выглядеть мне кажется.

Comment: Отдельные переменные полезны, если нужно еще какой декоратор (типа `login_required` или `token_required`) навесить на отдельный обработчик, а так-то да, чтоб убрать шум и все упроситить.